# How to filter some packages in EMMA code coverage generation for android project?

Tags: android, build, gradle, code-coverage, emma

I have an android project and I'm using gradle build. I have some packages from open source. I don't want this to be included in report generation since it decreases my code coverage. I researched EMMA documentation,but couldn't get things together to work. Any help?